# LLVM - Liveness Analysis to remove dead code

Tags: c++, llvm, compiler-optimization, dead-code

I'm trying to implement liveness analysis to remove dead instructions. I know that `isInstructionTriviallyDead()` exists, however, I want to learn how to remove code using def-use (or use-def) chains.

The way I am currently doing it is I am iterating through all the instructions in a block (using `inst_iterator`), and for each instruction, looping through all of its uses. Ultimately, if an instruction has no use, then I consider it dead, and can therefore remove it using `eraseFromParent()`

This looks something like:

```
for (inst_iterator I = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); I != E; ++I) { 
    bool deadInst = true;
    Instruction *inst = &*I;


    for (User* pUser : inst->users()) {
        // If we enter this loop, we have at least one use, so instruction isn't dead
        deadInst = false;
    }

    // deadInst is true if we didn't enter the loop, so has no uses
    if (deadInst) {
        inst->eraseFromParent();
    }
}
```

The problem is, a return instruction has no uses assosciated with it (and I'm sure there are other definitions with no uses). However a return instruction shouldn't be removed as it'll lead to semantically incorrect code.

Is my general approach to removing instructions via liveness analysis okay? What can I do to ensure instructions like return are not removed?

Any pointers are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

also check whether the instruction is a terminator instruction (`inst->isTerminator()`)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Could you provide more insight into this? Do you mean something such as `if (deadInst && !inst->isTerminator())`? What is a terminator function?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `llvm::isInstructionTriviallyDead`, and it's a good start to get some insights on what can be removed, and what cannot.

You already noticed that you can't remove terminator instruction.

Also, you don't want to remove instructions with no uses, but with side effects. Consider this:

```
define void @bar()() {
  call void @foo()()
  ret void
}
```

You don't want to remove `call` instruction, even if it has no uses, because, it can, for example, write to stdout or change some global variable. Same thing goes for `store`'s. Check `Instruction::mayHaveSideEffects` for the full list.

Your liveness analysis is too aggressive: no uses is *necessary*, but *not sufficient* condition for instruction to be considered dead.

If you do not want to use `isInstructionTriviallyDead` for learning purposes, I recommend you to start other way around: consider when instructions are dead for sure (for example, `alloca` is dead when there are no uses, so does `add` instruction...) and then generalize.

Additionally, simply loop through all instructions and removing dead ones is not sufficient. For example:

```
%2 = add i32 3, %1
%3 = add i32 3, %2
```

When you first encounter `%2`, it has a use in `%3`, so not dead. But after you eliminate `%3` as dead, `%2` becomes dead too. You can overcome this problem by iterating until no new dead instruction is found (ineffective, but simple), or by some recursive procedure.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Could I not use conditions such as `isTerminator()` or `mayHaveSideEffects()` in my `if (deadInst)` condition, to counteract the aggressiveness of the liveness analysis? I.e. we can assume that if the variable has no uses, is not a terminator instruction, and has no side effects, then it's same to remove. Or is this still too aggressive?

Comment: @user3186023, add [landing pad](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#landingpad-instruction) to the list, and I think it is enough to start with, but `llvm` also tries to preserve instructions with debug info, which you may or may not want to keep too.

Comment: Ah landing pad - the thing I understand very little about!  I've seen this in the source code for `IsInstructionTriviallyDead()` but couldn't understand what it did, nor could I find any documentation. Is there any LLVM documentation that might explain what a landing pad is?

Comment: Sorry - for some bizarre reason, the link to landing pad doc was not hyperlinked on my phone so it wasn't apparent that you provided  a link. I'll read through this, thanks a bunch!  I'm hoping with these 3 new checks that my liveness analysis won't be too aggressive and move instructions that may actually be needed.

Comment: @user3186023, there is a detailed explanation on how landing pad works here: http://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html.

Comment: Thanks for that link. While we're on the topic of liveness analysis, is there any built in libraries for LLVM that create the def, use, in and out sets commonly found in liveness analysis algorithms? For some reason I'm not totally convinced that my method is sufficient enough to do what `IsInstructionTriviallyDead()` does, and I have a feeling it will remove instructions that shouldn't be removed, in some cases.

Comment: @user3186023, I'm not aware of any such library, maybe you can find something in unit tests for `llvm` itself? Otherwise, you can compile some large project to `llvm ir`, apply both yours and builtin functions and compare results.

Comment: The code stated above `if (!instIsLive && !inst->isTerminator() && !inst->mayHaveSideEffects() && !isa<LandingPadInst>(inst)) {` does not capture print instructions. Is there anything I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks before delete instruciton, you should judge its function firstly.
With isa<>() to do this by

```cpp
if (isa<ReturnInst>(instruction) || isa<BranchInst>(instruction) || ...) {
  deadInst = false;
}
```